# Find the asymptotes of the following curve: $2r^2=\tan (2\theta)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the asymptotes of the following curve: $2r^2=\tan (2\theta)$

My Attempt:

Given curve is $$2r^2=\tan (2\theta)$$
$$r^2=\dfrac {1}{2} \cdot \tan (2\theta)$$
$$r=\sqrt {\dfrac {\tan (2\theta)}{2}}$$

Comment: I think you should try using half angle formula for $\tan 2\theta$ . But in any case, the places where $\tan 2\theta$ is not defined is the place to look.

Comment: @Mann : I disagree. I think it's much simpler without that.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\tan(2\theta) \to+\infty$ as $\theta\uparrow \pi/4.$ So $r\to+\infty$ as $\theta\uparrow\pi/4.$

So the line $\theta=\pi/4$ is an asymptote. That's the same as $x=y.$

Then think about periodicity of the trigonmetric function.